# Changing background of div using useState in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I want to be able to change the background of the div containing an array of names and age when it is active. I am using styled components. I want to only use useState hook for this without any router or anything.

How can I achieve this? I tried using a ternary operator in styled css but that uses #000 in the default state, i.e not active. What code changes can I make to set the div active?

**styled.css**

```
export const Style=styled.div<{active:boolean}> ((({active})=>({
   background-color: active? #0000 : transparent;
}));
```

**Person.tsx**

```
 type person={
      name: string;
      age: number;
    }

interface IdentifierProps{
  citizen: Array <Person>
}

export default function Person (props: IdentifierProps): ReactElement{
   const [ active, setActive]= useState(0);
   return(
     <div class="app">
     {props.citizen.map((all: person)=>(
      <Style key={all.name} href={} onClick={()=>setActive(all.name)} activeItem>
      </Style>
     </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to change the HEX in there to what you want it to change when active:

```
background-color: active? #bada55 : transparent;
```

However, this will change it to all of them, not just the one you clicked on. To achieve that, you need to track the active state of each element. You can do so by breaking the useState to more than just one, but

```
const [active, setActive]= useState({
person1Active: false,
person2Active: false,
person3Active: false,
});
```

Then you need to set these in the onClick.
Although I'm sure there's a more elegant solution out there.

Comment: this doesn't help. The default color of the div becomes #bada55 just like before. I want the color to change to #bada55 when it is active. I am not sure if my state is correct for which I need help

Comment: The idea is to not hardcode the values of individual items in array to false. I know that one better way is to have a unique key and parse through each id when active but I am not sure how can I do it for my code

Comment: Try setting the initial value of active in the useState as false, instead of 0. Then set it it true/false in the setActive.
Alternatively if you need an integer, check for active !== 0 ? #0000 : transparent;
in the ternary.

Comment: When I type false, I get an error on onClick={()=>setActive(all.name)}  "Argument of string is not assignable to parameter of type 'setStateAction' to boolean

Comment: yes, it will, all.name is not a boolean. That's why I wrote to set it true/false instead of a name.
Then you can refactor the way you mention by having id's and checking against those later.